# ffprobe query: get only the value without the label

Tags: ffmpeg

I use to get bitrate from video with this command:

> ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of
>   default=noprint_wrappers=1 output_1080.mp4

Result:

bit_rate=5013267

How to get only the value to insert it in a bash variable purpose?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the `nokey=1` format option. To assign it to a variable in bash you could do something like:

```sh
BITRATE="$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -i output_1080.mp4)"
```

You might also want to consider adding something like `-select_streams a:0` if you only want the first audio stream for example. Otherwise it might output multiple values.